# Anyone using Paypal for recurring payment?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payments

Are there any catch in using Paypal for recurring payment?

We are not in US/UK/CA, so seems there are not many options for recurring payment, for example, FastSpring charge us 8% for recurring payment which is insane and we can't afford.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Which country are you working from? What alternatives have you researched so far?

Comment: @Nick, I am from Taiwan

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are many alternatives.

One such alternative is [Stripe](https://stripe.com), which is geared towards developers and webmasters.

> Payments for developers
>   Stripe makes it easy to start accepting
>   credit cards on the web today.

If you want a solution that includes fraud checks, weekly bank payments, and recurring items, I'd say go with [2Checkout](https://www.2checkout.com), who let you accept Credit Cards and Paypal.

You set up your pre-defined products, or use the REST-like API to generate payment links on the fly; this includes recurring items, and even logic for handling shipping fees if applicable.

I personally use both of these guys, for various reasons, and recommend you give both a try. In all the months I've been using them, I've never had an issue, unlike with Paypal, where I've experienced more frustration than success.

There is one downside to 2CO's services, in that their fees are a bit higher than most of the competition (but still lower than the astronomical 8% !).

Both [Stripe](https://stripe.com) and [2Checkout](https://www.2checkout.com) are viable services that many have success with, and are more reasonable than FastSpring, while accepting payments internationally.

Comment: Please see [this meta thread](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/895/are-coupon-codes-okay-to-post)(about you), and quit posting the promo code, disclosure or no.

Comment: Sure, no problem, although I don't see the problem; I left full disclosure, and the code was related to my answer. I am suggesting that the questioner try both services to see which he likes, and this is impossible to do for free without the promo code.

Comment: If you disagree with the mod(s), take it up in meta, not here. I only asked the question. (Though I do agree.)

Answer (score -1):

Paypal recurring doesn't charge anything extra.  8% is ridiculous.  we are using paypal for recurring payment for our customer as well and it works very well.  I am not sure if it'll work in TW, but I assume it's all the same.